# Jmeter regular expression for Oracle DB output

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter , I have created a DB connection with Oracle, and executing below query.

```
select address , city , zip from table where city='Delhi';
```

Now this is giving result as:

```
212 Kamla nagar  Delhi  11011
```

Now I want to use this into 3 variable using regular expression and pass all these 3 parameters to another soap request.

I tried to use regular expression as `(\d+)` but it only stored value in variable 1.

How to extract values and use them in another request?

Answer (score 0):

you can use JDBC preprocessor and from which you use either `Variable names` or `Result variable name`

The ones you specify in the `Variable names` box map to individual columns returned by your query and these you can access by saying `columnVariable_{index}`.

***OR***

The one you specify in the `Result variable name` contains the entire result set and in practice this is a list of maps to values. The above syntax will obviously not work in this case. you will have to access it by `BeanShell` and create variables.

***...and then you can use these variables as `${name_1}`, `${city_1}`, `${zip_1}` in soap request to access value from DB. or as `${name}`, `${city}`, `${zip}` if you use `Result variable name` object***
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Amit1 - great - consider accepting answer as accepted answer (click on correct sign next to up/down arrow, and also click on up arrow) - this will encourage us to contribute more and more .... Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Configure your JDBC Sampler as follows:

[image: JMeter JDBC Results]

i.e. add the next line to "Variable Names" input:

```
address, city, zip
```

You will be able to access the extracted values as:

- `${address_1}`
- `${city_1}`
- `${zip_1}`

later in the script. `1` stands for Result Set row, i.e. if there will be 2 rows in JDBC response - `${address_1}` will stand for 1st row address, `${address_2}` - for 2nd row address, etc.

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for details.